# Clustering using two matrix

Tags: cluster-analysis

I've two matrix containing informations from 40 samples and 50000 genes. Matrix Expr contains the gene expression for each gene and samples; Matrix Methyl contains the methylation state of these genes for each samples. Is it possible to perform a clustering (on genes and/or samples) based on both expression and methylation informations ? I know how to perform a basic hierarchical clustering in R i.e; `hclust(dist(M))` but it's only on one matrix.. Any idea/advice ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a similarity that takes both matrixes into account.

Naively, this could be as easy as

```
dist <- dist(A) + dist(B)
```

however, clustering in general is extremely sensitive to scale, and these problem make any such approach very difficult. Sorry - there is no "correct" or automatic solution to this problem.

Comment: Maybe I could scale the expr and methyl matrix using the scale() function on every columns .. I'll try

Comment: You certainly *can*. The question you should be asking is how it affects your result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cluster Samples based on their (dis)similarities taking into account gene expression and methylation state, then you can consider that Gene Expression and Gene Methylation State for all the 50000 genes are all 'Features' of each sample.

So, you can concatenate both matrices Methyl and Expr, resulting in a 40x100000 matrix, and computing the dist() of that matrix.

Similarly, in case you want to cluster genes based on their differences, you can concatenate both matrices onto a 80x50000 matrix

Hope it helps.

Comment: The issue here is that gene expression and methylation are expressed using two different metrics (with a very different dynamic range).